# I want paragraph 3 to contiune just below the image

Tags: html, css

Help me find the problem that I am facing - I am not getting the solution of this code kindly help me fix my problem.

I want like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCIzT.png)

Here is my code

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.holder{
    font-family: arial;
    }
.holder .menu ul {
  text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
.holder .menu ul li{
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.holder .menu ul li:hover{
    background-color:  #33ff33  ;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}
.image_about_me {
    margin: 64px 117px auto;
    display: flex;
}

img {
    width: 350px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 76px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        



    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="holder">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About me</li>
    <li>Subscribe</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="image_about_me">
    <img src=image.jpg>

        <div class="about_me">
            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>

            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>
Madison believes mindfulness in the workplace is key to success - a tenet she lives out through her interests in yoga, meditation, gardening, and painting. Madison is currently working as a freelance marketing director and is always interested in a challenge. Reach out to madisonblackstone@gmail.com to connect!


            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>

            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>

            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using Flex?

Comment: Please check once https://code.makery.ch/library/more-html-css/image-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove flex from parent div, add class to image and set this class to float left.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.holder{
    font-family: arial;
    }
.holder .menu ul {
  text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
.holder .menu ul li{
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.holder .menu ul li:hover{
    background-color:  #33ff33  ;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}
.image_about_me {
    margin: 64px 117px auto;
}

img {
    width: 350px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 76px;
}

.image {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        



    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="holder">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About me</li>
    <li>Subscribe</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="image_about_me">
    <img src=image.jpg class="image">

        <div class="about_me">
            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>

            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>
Madison believes mindfulness in the workplace is key to success - a tenet she lives out through her interests in yoga, meditation, gardening, and painting. Madison is currently working as a freelance marketing director and is always interested in a challenge. Reach out to madisonblackstone@gmail.com to connect!


            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>

            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>

            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use of float, not flex nor grid .

Example without flex and a floatting image where the text can wrap around .

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.holder{
    font-family: arial;
    }
.holder .menu ul {
  text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
.holder .menu ul li{
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.holder .menu ul li:hover{
    background-color:  #33ff33  ;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}
.image_about_me {
    margin: 64px 117px auto;
     
}

img {
    width: 350px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 76px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        



    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="holder">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About me</li>
    <li>Subscribe</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="image_about_me">
    <img src=image.jpg>

        <div class="about_me">
            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>

            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>
Madison believes mindfulness in the workplace is key to success - a tenet she lives out through her interests in yoga, meditation, gardening, and painting. Madison is currently working as a freelance marketing director and is always interested in a challenge. Reach out to madisonblackstone@gmail.com to connect!


            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>

            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>

            <p>
Madison Blackstone is a director of brand marketing, with experience managing global teams and multi-million-dollar campaigns. Her background in brand strategy, visual design, and account management inform her mindful but competitive approach. Madison is fueled by her passion for understanding the nuances of cross-cultural advertising. She considers herself a ‘forever student,’ eager to both build on her academic foundations in psychology and sociology and stay in tune with the latest digital marketing strategies through continued coursework.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```